# Send ExpressJS MySql query response to a simple JS file to edit HTML table

Tags: mysql, node.js, express

i'm using ExpressJS as server, and MySql as local db.
I need to get some data from a table and send the query result to a vanilla JS file or just edit HTML trought NodeJS, but i don't know how...

My Express server:

```
const express = require("express");
const app = express();
const path = require("path");

app.use(express.static("../public"));

app.get("/home", function(req, res) {
  res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname + "/../index.html"));
});
```

Comment: It's unclear what you mean by "send the query result to a vanilla JS file or just edit HTML" ... Please give us a fuller idea of your goal and what you have tried.

Answer (score 1):

1- To query from your database tables, you'll need to use a Node.js MySQL client or an ORM, I use [mysql](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mysql) in the following example:

```
const mysql      = require('mysql');
const connection = mysql.createConnection({
  host     : 'localhost',
  user     : 'me',
  password : 'secret',
  database : 'my_db'
});

connection.connect();
```

2- Write your query and send back the results to the end-user

```
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();

router.get('/home', function(req, res, next) {
  connection.query('SELECT * FROM `tablename`;', function (error, results, fields) {
    if (error) throw error;
    res.send({ results });
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to choose a template engine like [pug](https://expressjs.com/en/guide/using-template-engines.html)

You should connect to your database as mentioned before : 
    const mysql = require('mysql');
    const connection = mysql.createConnection({
      host     : 'localhost',
      user     : 'me',
      password : 'secret',
      database : 'my_db'
    });

```
connection.connect();
```

and make your query form your TableName :

```
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();

    router.get('/home', function(req, res, next) {
      connection.query('SELECT * FROM `tablename`;', function (error, results, fields) {
        if (error) throw error;
        res.render('index', { 'data' : results })
      });
    });
```

And for your template page :

```
 ul
      each val, index in data
        li= index + ': ' + val
```